# Prove that $n$ is prime if and only if for every integer $a$ , either $hcf ( a, n ) = 1 $or $n ∣ a$ assuming n ≥ 2

Tags: prime-numbers

So the question is an 'if and only if' statement meaning that it needs to be proved both ways. I have proved the first direction (if $n$ is prime then either $hcf(a,n)=1$ or $a∣n$). However, I am struggling to prove the opposite direction.

Comment: You can let $a$ run through $2,3,4,\ldots,n-1$. Does any of those $a$ divide your $n$? What can you conclude? (By the way, what is the definition of prime you use?)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen that the prime's has only divisors, itself and 1. Also, surely some number between 2 and _n-1_ would divide _n_ as you cannot assume it is prime doing the backwards implication?

Comment: You cannot assume $n$ is prime in this direction, but you do need to _prove_ that $n$ is prime. One way of doing the latter would be to check that no non-trivial divisor $a$ exists. Agree?

Comment: hcf = highest common factor , isn't it  ? You should mention it as it is not a very classical abbreviation.

Comment: Likely duplicate: [Let $x$ be greater than $1$. Prove $x$ is prime if and only if for every integer $y$, either $\gcd(x,y)=1$ or $x\mid y$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645440/)